# Uncaught ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onload, onload-event

Trying to correct my bounce rate in Google Analytics and I found this snippet very handy. It does the job but at the same time it triggers an error like "_gaq is not defined" in Dev Console...

`// <![CDATA[(function (tos) {window.setInterval(function () {tos = (function (t) {return t[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(t[1]) + 1) + ':00' : (t[1] || '0') + ':' + (parseInt(t[0]) + 10);})(tos.split(':').reverse());window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);}, 10000);})('00');// ]]>`

Comment: The `_gaq` object is associated with classic GA. If you are using the newer Universal Analytics, then you would need to modify the code to use the `ga` object instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message indicates that the `_gaq` object does not exist, and this could be true if you are not using Classic GA for your tracking, but are instead using Universal Analytics. If you are using Universal Analytics, you would need to update your `_gaq.push` code to:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Time', 'Log', tos);
```

Comment: Add it below, and you just need to replace your `_gaq` call with my code above.

Comment: Should I need to add the snippet above in the GA script? If not, can you edit the snippet please?

Comment: First of all, are you using classic GA or universal?

Comment: I'm using Universal.

Comment: Sorry mate, that was my fault. I apologize and THANK YOU very much! The snippet you gave me works perfectly good!

Comment: No worries! Cheers, mate!